# Creating Filter fields outside of a Grid in Vaadin

Tags: java, filter, vaadin

I'm trying to create some filters for a Grid in Vaadin (Java) and I don't want to use the GridCellFilter.

I want to reach this goal by creating a TextField and a ComboBox and I should be able to filter elements inside the grid when I write in the TextField AND when I select an element of the ComboBox (separately or at the same time).

Can you please provide me some example of how to do it?

I am new in Vaadin.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you see an example of how you can create a TextField filter.

Setting ValueChangeMode.EAGER will allow filtering whenever the user presses a key in the TextField.

```
@Route(value = "customer-revenue-jpa-records", layout = ApplicationLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Customer Revenue JPA Records")
public class CustomerRevenueV20JpaRecordView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final Grid<CustomerInfo> grid;

    public CustomerRevenueV20JpaRecordView(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;

        setHeightFull();

        TextField filter = new TextField();
        filter.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);
        filter.addValueChangeListener(event -> loadData(event.getValue()));
        filter.setPlaceholder("Search");

        add(filter);

        grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.addColumn(CustomerInfo::id).setHeader("ID").setSortable(true).setSortProperty("id");
        grid.addColumn(CustomerInfo::firstname).setHeader("First Name").setSortable(true).setSortProperty("firstname");
        grid.addColumn(CustomerInfo::lastname).setHeader("Last Name").setSortable(true).setSortProperty("lastname");
        grid.addColumn(CustomerInfo::revenue).setHeader("Revenue");

        loadData("");

        grid.setHeightFull();

        add(grid);
    }

    private void loadData(String name) {
        grid.setItems(
                query -> customerRepository.findAllCustomersWithRevenue(
                        PageRequest.of(query.getPage(), query.getPageSize(), toSpringDataSort(query)), name).stream(),
                query -> customerRepository.countCustomersWithRevenue(name)
        );
    }
}
```